# Redux store seems to still persist some data upon clicking back button [Firefox]

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm pretty new to Redux and I'm working on a project where there involves some user auth and data associated with that user gets loaded after the user is verified. After the user logs out, I clear the store by doing

```
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === USER_LOGOUT) {
    state = undefined;
    window.location = "somePage.jsp";
  }
  return appReducer(state, action);
};
```

On Chrome, when I click the back button, the store doesn't have any residual information so this works as expected.

However, on Firefox, when I click on the back button I've found that the store still persists some data.

Am I missing something in my steps to clearing out my store or is there a different behavior in Firefox?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should probably also return in the logout block.

if (action.type === USER_LOGOUT) {
    state = undefined;
    window.location = "somePage.jsp";
    return {}
  }

Comment: How you inspect 'store' which make you sure that it still exists after click 'back button'? I am using similar technique too.

Comment: How you inspect 'store' which make you sure that it still exists after click 'back button'? I am using similar technique too.